# Struts2 datepickers breaks into separate lines when used inside a table

Tags: html, struts2, datetimepicker

I am using struts2 `datepicker` and have a scenario in which I have to mention dates in the format of:

**From: [Date] To: [Date]**
but whenever I am using

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <sx:datetimepicker label= "From" />
      <sx:datetimepicker label= "To" /> 
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

this breaks the components into four separate lines. I want them to be in one line. I have also used styles like "inline" and "inline-block" but nothing works.

```
Expected Result:

From: [Date] To: [Date]

Current Result:
From: [Date]
To:   [Date]
```

Comment: First of all `struts2-dojo-plugin` is deprecated years ago. Second read about themes in Struts2: http://struts.apache.org/development/2.x/docs/themes-and-templates.html.

Comment: Thanks, if it is depreciated I will discontinue using it. Can you suggest some stable datepicker to use with Struts 2?

Comment: Take a look at `struts2-jquery-plugin`: http://code.google.com/p/struts2-jquery/.

Answer (score 0):

In one line then use two columns in the table

```
<td>
  <sj:datetimepicker label= "From" />
</td><td>
  <sj:datetimepicker label= "To" /> 
</td>
```

Answer (score -1):

use theme as simple instead of xhtml.By Default theme  is xhtml. 
for example:

```
<s:div theme="simple" />
```